# row count after filtering in RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

How can I get row count for RadGrid after filtering, when result grid has got several pages.

```
 radGrid.MasterTableView.Items.Count
```

returns page size in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
private int totalItemCount;
protected void RadGrid1_ItemEvent(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EventInfo is GridInitializePagerItem)
    {
        totalItemCount = (e.EventInfo as GridInitializePagerItem).PagingManager.DataSourceCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If paging is enabled, the items.Count will only show page size. One thing you can do it set paging to false, bind the grid, get the count, set paging to true, and then rebind the grid.

```
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.AllowPaging = false;
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Rebind();
int totalCount = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items.Count;
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.AllowPaging =true;
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Rebind();
```

Another thing you can do is to get the count by counting the GridDataItem items in the ItemDataBound grid event.

For more on this, see this [Telerik help page](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/total-record-count-after-filter.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Rebinding without paging is helps  but I have more than 350 pages and 7k+ items so it is not very good move for my grid.